# 'Reverse Engineering' this unsubscribe link?

Tags: ampscript, cloudpage

I'm trying to grok the way my company's existing unsubscribes are handled - specifically, this link in the footer of our SFMC emails that's somehow passing data to the unsubscribe page:

```
 <a alias="Footer_Unsub" conversion="true" data-linkto="other" href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(507,'local','GBen'))=%%" style="color:#7F7F7F;text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank" title=""><u>click here to unsubscribe</u></a>
```

I'm not sure if it's down to one of `conversion="true"` and `data-linkto="other"` (which don't appear to be 'standard' HTML attributes) or something inherent to the use of `RedirectTo`/`CloudPagesURL` within an email, but the page is able to use `set @customer_ID = _subscriberkey`and `set @customer_Email = emailaddr` when reached from the link in question so they must be being passed somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CloudPagesURL](https://ampscript.guide/book/cloudpagesurl/) : This function provides a convenient method of linking to landing pages (created in CloudPages) from email messages.
When an email is sent that includes a link to a landing page with this function, a URL link is generated to the landing page and is appended with an encrypted query string.
**This encrypted query string provides a reference to the email, which means that system personalization strings can be used on a landing page to retrieve values related to the sent email(Because of the reference being passed you're not seeing anything explicitly set on the hyperlink as the landing page will have the reference to the email send)**. And as the string is encrypted, no Subscriber information is passed in clear text.

An email is sent that includes the following link to a landing page using the CloudPagesURL function(Your actual code will consist this below hyperlink if you see the code view of the email template where 123 is the unique Id of the cloud page):

```
<a href="%%=CloudPagesURL(123)=%%">click here to visit your landing page</a>
```

The following HTML is used on the landing page. The _subscriberKey personalization string is used to retrieve a corresponding value from a Data Extension.

```
%%[

var @firstName
set @firstName = Lookup("Members", "First Name", "Subscriber Key", _subscriberKey)

]%%

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <body>
          <h2>Hello %%=v(@firstName)=%%,</h2>
          <p>Welcome to your personalized landing page.</p>
       </body>
    </html>
```

**Output :**
The CloudPagesURL function returns the page URL of the landing page appended with an encrypted query string with Subscriber data. 
For example: https://pub.exacttarget.com/adytgmabc?qs=bfd0bc86b7b0dc08be758fc47e321b5e

The page is personalized with a Data Extension field value, which is based on the Subscriber Key of the email sent to the Subscriber.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>Hello Andrew,</h2>
      <p>Welcome to your personalized landing page.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Other than the above the [CloudPagesURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm)function can also accept  additional parameter included in encrypted query string

```
%%=CloudPagesURL(ID, 'CampaignCode', @CampCode, 'SegmentName', @SegmentName)=%%
```